# auto layout rotation fix position

Tags: ios, rotation, autolayout

Hi i'm struggling with the auto layout in xcode5. Maybe I'm totally wrong and there is another way to get my desired result.

take a look:

this is my portrait view how i made it in Interface Designer

[image]

this is how i want the button to stay and rotate in landscape

[image]

So is there a way to accomplish this in interface builder and auto layout or is there another way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

There is 2 ways: short and "right".

**Short way**

1. Add notification in viewDidLoad (and don't forget to unsubscribe in dealloc)

   // don't forget the first line, otherwise you won't ger orientation.
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) 
   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
2. Add constraint Bottom spacing View - Superview
3. Connect this constraint to your code (as you connect outlets)
4. If orientationChanged method set required value:

   self.constaint.constant = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) ? 10 : 200;

**Right way**

All code dealing with constraints should go to - (void) updateConstraints of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the button to move from all the way at the bottom to all the way at the top. That's not going to happen automagically! You'll to have move the button yourself in code. Implement `viewWillLayoutSubviews` on your view controller and position the button there.